# CMake + Ninja : argument list too long

Tags: cmake

On Kubuntu 18.04 with CMake 3.10.2, Ninja 1.9.0 (from git) and gcc 9.1.0 I've got error

```
fatal: posix_spawn: Argument list too long
```

while compilation of my project. Google say that this problem was fixed, but this is probably false (in fact, for me :). I've updated to latest version of cmake, ninja and g++, but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184251/cmake-command-line-too-long-windows

Comment: @kutschkem, unfortunately, it didn't help.